When a moderator upvotes a comment on a site they moderate, the error message "You cannot mark a comment more than once" shows up
I recently upvoted a comment (first time upvoting that specific comment) on my meta site and received an error message stating "You cannot mark a comment more than once." Another mod mentioned they encountered the same thing occurring on their site.
After a bit of testing, it seems to only affect moderators when they are voting on a site they moderate.

Possibly related to this bug or its fix.
As mentioned by @Makyen,

The bug is that two POST requests are sent when the comment upvote button is clicked. Depending on the time between them and the exact servers which they hit, I'd expect to intermittently see an error.

I have also confirmed myself that 2 POST requests are sent when I upvote a comment. The first succeeds, while the second fails with the above error message.

I think it's possible this is only happening on sites that we moderate. If you think this comment is useful you may even be able to test that here.

@BryanKrause seems likely as i can upvote your comment without the bug occurring.

Reproduced here - upvoted Bryan's comment, that succeeded, but I got the same message as you did. With my sockpuppet account, it doesn't happen, so Bryan's observation is spot on.

Definitely a bug. Definitely only seen on the site where I'm a moderator. The bug is that two POST requests are sent when the comment upvote button is clicked. Depending on the time between them and the exact servers which they hit, I'd expect to intermittently see an error (e.g., I, twice, saw both POST requests succeed, but would expect failure if the requests were further apart in time or happened to hit the same server).

Consequently, you are unable to unupvote a comment you’ve upvoted.

Related, and likely the same root cause: Moderators trying to delete or undelete comments are now prompted to confirm (and canceling does not work)

Two bugfixes went out just a bit ago -- one for this problem, and one for the related issue re: mod deletes and undeletes.

Can confirm that I am able to upvote comments on the site I moderate without the error popup, and I'm only seeing one POST now. Thanks!
